# Percentage change explanation

Tags: percentages

When I want to calculate the percentage change between two values over time.. I use this formula:

`((customers2014 - customers2013) / (customers2013) * 100)`

What's the difference between divide the difference between 2014 and 2013 by the newest value instead of oldest value?

Comment: I don't have enough points to comment. This feels related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2896701.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in what the baseline for comparison is.

If an apple costs 1 dollar on monday and it costs $1.2$ dollars on tuesday, then the apple costs $20\%$ **more** on tuesday than it did on monday. The term "than it did on monday" is important, because it tells you relative to *what* you are calculating. So, in my example:

- I can say that the apple costs $20\%$ more on tuesday than it does on monday
- Or I can say that the apple cost $16.7\%$ **less** on monday than it does on tuesday.

The number you are dividing by, basically, is your "unit of comparison".