# In percent change, why do we divide the difference by the original number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a = 90$ and $b = 100$, and we are calculating the percent increase going from $a$ to $b$, we calculate the actual numerical difference $b - a = 10$.

But why divide the difference into the starting value $a$? How does seeing how many times $90$ goes into $10$ give a a percentage of increase?

(Obviously we multiply by $100\%$ for a percentage.)

Comment: Because we take "a" as reference. We need to divide by the starting value, because we want to know what the percentage increase is from the perspective of "a". If we already have "a" as percentage before, and now we go to "b", what's the percentage increase from "a" ? That's why we need to divide the difference by our starting value. If a = 5% and b=15%, the difference is 10% and the percentage increase seen from the perspective of "a" is 200%, because for "a" to go from 5% to 15%, it has "to cover a distance" of 10%, which is 200% our reference "a", does that make sense ?

Comment: In your example with a=90 and b=100, we need to increase "a" by 1/9 to go to "b". 1/9 of "a" is 10, which is your percentage difference. Basically you can ask yourself how many times "a" fits in our percentage difference, because we will need to increase "a" by this result to cover the distance to "b", does that make sense ?

Comment: Basically, we need to divide by our starting percentage because we take it as our reference, so everything is seen according to this reference. I hope you understand what I say ;)

Comment: We do not multiply by $100$ to get a "better reading". We multiply by $100\%$ to convert a fraction to a percentage. An increase from 90 to 100 increases 90 by $\frac{10}{90}=\frac{1}{9}$. We then multiply by $1=100\%$ to get $11\frac{1}{9}\%$.

Answer (score 2):

If you change $a=a\cdot (1)$ to $a\cdot (1+d)$ then $d$ is called the proportionate change in $a$. Since "percent" literally means $1/100,$ the  proportionate change in $a$ is $d=(100d)\times (1/100)=100d$ % .

If $a$ changes to $b$ then $a(1+d)=b$ so $d=(b/a)-1=(b-a)/a.$

Examples. (1). Your pay rate has been doubled from $a$ to $b=2a.$ Then $d=1$ . You have a $100$% raise.

(2). Your grade has been amended from $90$ to $99$. This is a $10$% increase. The increase $99-90=9$ is $10$% of your original grade  $(90).$

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about this might be to consider a situation in which you *don't know* either the starting or ending number.  Suppose, for example, I tell you that the price of something goes up \$19.  Is that a big increase, or a small increase?  It depends on what the original price was, of course.  If the original price was \$20, then an increase of \$19 is huge -- the price almost doubled.  On the other hand, if the original price was \$240,000 (let's say you're buying a house) than an increase of \$19 is basically pocket change.

So intuitively, the way we apprehend the size of an increase depends on what the original size was.  Percents allow us to quantify that intuitive sense.  In the first example, a \$19 increase on an original price of \$20 is an increase of 95% (that is, the increase is almost as large as the entire original price).  In the second example, a \$19 increase an an original price of \$240,000 is just 0.0079%.  Dividing the increase by the base amount allows you to measure the increase *relative to* something -- it sets the "scale", so to speak.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct in dividing $b-a$ by $a $ to find the percent increase.
It does not make sense to divide $10$ by $100$ to find the percent increase. We have to divide $10$ by $90$, then multiply by $100$ to get the  percentage increase.

Comment: This is hardly an explanation.